# Serve webpages on a vps running nextcloud server

Tags: apache, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud Hub 6 (27.1.1) instance running on a vps with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Nextcloud works great. I have a domain name that I have set to be pointed to Nextcloud for web access. I would like to use another domain name that I can use to access web pages on my vps. I direct the domain to the IP address, and when I point a webbrowser to the domain name, I get a nextcloud-styled page that says "Access through untrusted domain". This tells me that a webserver is running, great. If I type in a terminal on my local machine:

```
telnet myip 80
```

I get:

```
Trying myip...
Connected to myip.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

And if I then type:

```
get foo
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 25 Oct 2023 01:26:29 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So its an apache server. Great. If I ssh into the vps and run htop, two of the task commands are:

```
/bin/sh /snap/nextcloud/37720/bin/run-httpd -k start -DFORGROUND
/bin/sh /snap/nextcloud/37720/bin/httpd-wrapper -k start -DFORGROUND
```

So nextcloud is running its own webserver which makes sense. That is as far as I have gotten. My question is: how do I serve web pages from my vps? Can/should I use nextcloud's webserver? If so, how do I configure it? If not, what should I do?

Comment: Looks like that apache server is setup as a frontend server that only proxies requests to that nextcloud http serer. Whyever, this does not exactly sound like an efficient setup. But it is possible sure, and maybe even necessary if you are using snap ṕackages for nextcloud. So what keeps you from looking into the apache configuration to add separate virtual hosts for those separate domains? That way you can configure the host service the "web page domain" independently from the virtual host proxying the nextcloud requests.

Comment: Yes, I can find out how to add virtual hosts from web searches, no problem. But with the snap installation, things appear much different than in all of the examples I find. Eg., nothing (apache stuff) is in the default locations, etc. So I am afraid to make a change that renders my nextcloud service unusable, which I cannot afford. I was hoping that I might be able to leave nextcloud's apache untouched and serve web pages separately. But I will give what you suggest a try and just be careful.

Comment: But what you wrote before suggests that this apache server is only a frontend server, not the one actually packaged by nextcloud. Maybe I got that wrong, though. To try things you obviously need a testing or development environment, one _never_ tests using a production setup. And for setting up vhosts I recommend to prefer the actual documentation over arbitrary examples you find somewhere on the internet. You need to understand what you actually do, not copy some lines.